# Getting trouble in installing tag lib in Apache tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I have application and I want to use `jstl tag lib`.

I have two jars `JSTL.jar` and `standard.jar`. I put both in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

I configure it in `web.xml` like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/sql.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/x</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/x.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loadingServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>loadingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loadingServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loadingServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>homepage.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and on page i am using following code

```
<%@taglib prefix="k" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and still i am getting error. like

```
    INFO: Deploying web application directory ServletExample
13 Apr, 2012 4:00:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent with specification version
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibLocationRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:1167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1282)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2747)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1055)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
13 Apr, 2012 4:00:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/ServletExample/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent with specification version
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2713)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1285)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2747)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
```

Comment: Following solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8983170/2421561

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You made several mistakes:

- You should not manually redefine JAR's own taglibs in `web.xml`. This is a myth.
- You should be using a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` for Tomcat 7.
- You should be using JSTL 1.2, not 1.0.

Remove them all. Remove all `<taglib>` from `web.xml`. Remove the both JARs from `/WEB-INF/lib`. Then follow the following steps:

1. Download [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) and drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. Fix your `web.xml` to be Servlet 3.0 compatible.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app 
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

       <!-- Config here. No taglibs! -->

   </web-app>
   ```
3. Use the [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) taglib declaration:

   ```xml
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

---

I have a vague suspicion that you're using Roseindia.net as a Java EE resource. Your invalid approach is also mentioned in there. You should not do that. You should put that site in your Internet blacklist. This site is so full of bad answers and bad practices. Use Oracle's official resources instead, or Stackoverflow.com of course.

Comment: yes. all works fine. but some times i am using Roseindia for titorial.and i like stackoverFlow because of persons like you. who are giving answers very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are one of the lucky few that have to support old code and removing `taglib` in your `web.xml` is not an option. You can enclose it in `<jsp-config>` like so:

```
<jsp-config>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/taglibs/custom-taglib</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/custom-taglib.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: in which file would I need to place this part of code and where?

Comment: @davejal `web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure taglibs in web.xml anymore. Plus you're defining different taglib urls (iirc the web.xml ones are correct).

Use the uris from your web.xml in the jsp and remove the web.xml taglib defs.

Comment: yes. i already done that. and i am getting error on JSP like jasperException.

Comment: @kshitij Well, that's how you do it. I have no idea what this other error you get is, what version of JSTL you're using, what implementation, why you're using an old servlet spec version, etc.

Comment: jstl-1.0.1.jar and standard-1.0.1.jar

Comment: Those may be the earlier uris.

Comment: so i have to use new versions?

Comment: @kshitij No, you have to use the correct URIs. I don't know why you *wouldn't* use the most recent version, but that's a different issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10043/discussion-between-kshitij-and-dave-newton)